# Angular2 : Error during evaluation of click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

Im making request through a button from client to server that i created using express, in request handler there is only console.log('Delete from server');
every time im clicking on it im getting these errors

```
angular2.dev.js:23514 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: T
ypeError: Cannot read property    'request' of undefined
angular2-polyfills.js:143 Uncaught EXCEPTION:
Error during evaluation of   "click"
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
```

The file structure is, there are two folders server and client that have angular and server files respectively

Here is function on button click:

```
 deletefromserver(){
     this.http.request("http://localhost:3000/deletedata").subscribe((res :     Response) => {
        console.log(res.json());
    })     
 }
```

And this is request handler in server file:

```
server.get('/deletedata', function(){
console.log('Delete from server');
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot to inject the http service in your component

You should have something like:

```
@Component({...})
class MyComponent {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  deleteFromServer() {
    this.http.request("http://localhost:3000/deletedata").subscribe((res : Response) => { console.log(res.json()); })
  }

}
```

And don't forget to add the `HTTP_PROVIDERS` in your bootstrap:

```
bootstrap(MyComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

Your server should also return something:

```
server.get('/deletedata', function(req, res) {
  res.json({hello: 'hello world'});
});
```

Comment: Probably because your server is not running on the port 3000. That's not related to Angular 2 and your original question should be solved if you have this error.

Comment: Your server is not returning anything as it is just doing a console.log, maybe you should return a response if you don't want a 404? I updated my answer

Comment: @flyingHawk did you try?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you forget to inject the `Http` instance into your component:

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private http:Http) {
  }
}
```

Don't forget to add corresponding providers when bootstrapping your main component:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ HTTP_PROVIDERS ]);
```

Comment: If you use the lite-server, you can only use static content so I guess you don't have a `deletedata` file... That's the reason of the 'not found' error.

Comment: deletedata is request handler in server file

Comment: I guess that your server isn't started on the port 3000 ;-) only the angular2 application is...